# Force moments and angular momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

Suppose we have two thrusters on a satellite. The [thrust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust), given by the velocity of exhaust multiplied by its mass flow, produces a force on the satellite.

Thus, if we use a given amount of propellant, we can think of those thrusters as source of forces during a given time.

Now consider we place the thrusters that way and turn them on simultaneously:

[image]

In the case where $l_2$ is higher, the resulting torque will also be higher. If we adjust the other satellite masses so that moment of inertia is the same for both, it will result in a higher final angular velocity (arbitrarily higher if we increase $l$).

Since we use the same amount of propellant, I would except the final energy to be the same
Thus, what is going wrong here ?

Comment: If moment of inertia is same, energy invested is same, then I am not able to understand the point you are trying to make here that why will they have different angular speeds?

Comment: If we consider thrusters as source of forces, then they would provide more torque because of a bigger arm, thus resulting in more angular acceleration.

Comment: Quasi-infinite arm would result in quasi infinite angular acceleration for the same inertia; so I assume something is wrong about considering thrusters are source of forces or impulses

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful, there is no energy conservation. The exhaust ejection can be seen as a reversed perfectly inelastic collision. Energy is therefore needed to the combined system rocket and exhaust.

Mathematically, let $v$ the velocity of a rocket of mass $m$ with exhaust velocity $v_0$, then:
$$
\frac{dE}{dt} = -\frac{\dot m}{2}v_0^2 >0
$$

Now you can still argue that if both thrusters use up the same amount of fuel, then they require the same energy. Your problem would still remain.

Remember that that while the total energy used is the same, not all of it goes to speeding up the rocket. Part of it goes to speeding up the propellant. This, it is not obvious that the final energy of the two rockets be the same or different, you need to do the math.

It is not even so obvious that the final angular velocity increases with $l$. While it is true that the torque increases, so does the moment of inertia. The reasoning works for small $l$ where the effect on moment of inertia is negligible.

Mathematically, writing $\omega$ the angular velocity and $I$ the moment of inertia of the rocket:
$$
(I+2l^2m)\dot\omega=-2l\dot m v_0
$$
As you can see, you’d naively expect the inertia contribution to dominate for large $l$ and expect the scaling $\Delta\omega \propto l^{-1}$ (this will turn out to be false). Using the dimensionless mass:
$$
x=\frac{2ml^2}{I}
$$
You get:
$$
\Delta\omega = \frac{v_0}{l}(x+\ln(1+x))
$$
From the formula is not obvious that $\Delta\omega$ increases with $l$ due to the second term, but if you do the math it will turn out to be true.

Thus, it is true that final angular velocity increases with length. While the input energy is the same, more of the energy is transferred to the propellant as $l$ decreases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I am not sure to follow your differential equation, since the torque is the time derivative of angular momentum $I \omega$. If the mass varies shouldn't it be $- 2 l m v_0 = \dot I \omega + I \dot \omega$ ? (With I having the sum of the rocket inertia and the propellant inertia)

Comment: This is why I separated the rocket and the propellant’s inertia. $I$ is the moment of inertia of the rocket only, so is constant.  The $2ml^2$ is the varying contribution of the propellant with $m$ the remaining mass of propellant per thruster.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a term like $2 l^2 \dot m \omega$ ?

Comment: No it’s the same reasoning as for the [rocket equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation):$$m\dot v=-\dot m v_0 $$ and you don’t have an additional $\dot mv$ term.